# Wash Trade Definition

Tags: securities

I am a bit new to trading and hope that I am making this post in the appropriate place to ask. I saw a few questions on wash trading but I am still a bit confused on the specifics (I describe a specific use case below)

I have been mostly day-trading, looking for volatile assets that I can see big profits in a short time period. I have also been doing some reading on different forms of market manipulation to make sure I'm not doing something wrong. While most of these (like pump-and-dump) are relatively hard to accidentally do, there were a few practices which I had some questions on.

The first one I was wondering about is wash trading. I can definitely understand how wash trading where you buy and sell to/from yourself at same price is bad since this artificially creates volume without changing ownership. However, what if the buy and sell limits are different? For example, suppose an imaginary asset is at $10.50. I expect this asset to simultaneously go down to $10 and up to $11 within the same hour. In this scenario, the goal would be to profit from its volatility. Is this acceptable to have both orders open at the same time or is this still considered wash trading?, Furthermore, what if after it sells at 11, I double my buy order at 10? Is this a good (and more importantly legal) trading strategy? I am having a difficult time finding a solid explanation of the differences between illegal wash trading and perfectly valid day trading and am a bit nervous to continue without understanding this point.